# Usage: to which?

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses

I found the following sentence while reading technical documentation 
but the use of "to which" doesn't seem right, which expression would you use here ?

> Returns a list of lists where the elements **to which** 
>   function is true are grouped together.

Comment: The function declaration may help clarify this. It would almost make sense as "Returns a list of lists where the elements **for** which **the** function is true are grouped together."  But I still don't know what the lists of elements are, and what the function is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right: it doesn't make sense.  In fact, without knowing the context, I'm not comfortable guessing at the actual meaning.

But the most straightforward way I see here is: replace **to** with **for**, and *function* needs an article, presumably **the**:

> Returns a list of lists where the elements **for** which **the** function is true are grouped together.

So the command returns a list, which consists of lists of grouped elements for each of which the function (whatever it is) returns *true*.  I hope I got the original intent right.

Answer (score -2):

It seems correct to me. You could also write it like this:

> Returns a list of lists where the elements **which** function is **to** true
>   are grouped together.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Neither the original sentence nor your variation make sense to me.